# “What is its name” vs “What is the name of it”

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, construction, phrase-structure

Let’s say a friend of mine is listening to a song, and I heard the song while he is listening to it; and I wonder what the song is called. Can I use these sentences interchangeably to ask him the name of the song.

- “That is a nice song. What is the name of it?”
- “That is a nice song. What is its name?”

  I think “its name” would be more usual, but “the name of it” can be used too. Do you think I am right?

Comment: I have never heard anyone say "What is the name of it?"; it sounds strange to me. Maybe others have heard it. The second is fine.

Comment: @AIQ To me that sounds fine, I am not a native speaker of English though. However, I am wondering why it sounds off to you. I mean, is it also unusual to say "what is the name of that car"?

Comment: More idiomatic would be "What's it called?", or just "What's that song?". For the car example, "What make is it?".

Comment: @Cardinal Particularly because I have never heard anyone say it like that. It might be a regional thing, but I doubt it's commonly used. "What is the name of that car?" (which is idiomatic) is very different than "What is the name of it?" The weight at the end is different. See the answer here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246897/give-him-it-give-it-to-him-vs-give-john-it-give-it-to-john

Comment: @Cardinal Also, I can't quite tell if there is a situation where "What is the name of it?" would be more suitable than "What is the name of this [thing]?" or "What is the name of that [thing]?" I would say "What is the name of this car?" if I am standing next to it; I wouldn't say "What is the name of it?" Would you?

Comment: @AIQ That's a very interesting thing that I haven't noticed before. Yes, for some reason that I am not aware of, I would say, what's the name of this car.

Comment: @AIQ Thank you. Why does “name of it” sound strange to you? We can say “part of it”, “”smell of it”’ “taste of it”, “ends of it” etc. as far as I know. For example, at 3:40 in this video, the native speaker says “grab the ends of it” instead of “grab its ends” https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0fPanmOb_Os  Why not “name of it”?

Comment: @FireandIce You should add that link in your question. It would make a good source for that type of construction. Note that my objection was with "What is the name of it?". But I also feel the same about "What is the smell/taste of it?" I just wouldn't say it. Others might. Look at my other comments. The better alternatives, which are much more idiomatic, are "What is its name?", "What does it smell like?", and "Grab the ends of the towel.". If I know these, I have no reason to phrase it in a way that ends with "it". It can be used in informal speech (like the YouTube video), (cont.)

Comment: @FireandIce  (cont.) but it isn't very nice to hear, at least for me. You should add your comment to your question - you have a good argument. I am looking forward to see what others have to say.

Comment: @Jack Thanks. I know the sentences you gave can be said, but I wondered how correct it is to use “name of it.”

Comment: It's grammatically correct, and you will be understood, but as soon as you say it, everyone will know you are not a native speaker.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but curiously I think that saying "What's the name of that song?" is perfectly idiomatic. But saying "What's its name?" isn't